# Getting ValueError during One Hot Encoding

Tags: python, valueerror, one-hot-encoding

This is my dataset snippet:

[data1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IBpS.jpg)

During data wrangling phase, I have done the following:

```
len(house_df['location'].unique())
```

output: 1304
Now, I moved some locations that have less than 10 occurrences to a new label 'others'

```
house_df.location = house_df.location.apply(lambda x: str(x).strip())
location_count = house_df['location'].value_counts(ascending=False)
len(location_count[location_count<10])
places_location_count = location_count[location_count<10]
house_df.location = house_df.location.apply(lambda x: 'others' if x in places_location_count else x)
len(house_df.location.unique())
```

output: 255 & that's all for **'location'** column.
Now, during One Hot Encoding, I wrote:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
house_df['location'] = house_df['location'].astype(str)
ohe = OneHotEncoder(drop='first')
transformed_data = ohe.fit_transform(house_df[['location']])
col_name = ohe.get_feature_names_out()
house_df1 = pd.DataFrame(transformed_data, columns=col_name)
```

and getting the error:

`ValueError: Shape of passed values is (10797, 1), indices imply (10797, 251)`.

Just before one hot encoding, `house_df['location'].nunique()`gives 252 as I did some more data manipulation in some other columns.
`transformed_data.shape` >>(10797, 251). The difference of 1 is because of the `ohe = OneHotEncoder(drop='first')` which is necessary to avoid multicollinearity.

So I don't know why this **ValueError** is coming.

Any help is appreciated.